# Freeing malloced structure in a function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm creating a source files containing buffer functionality that I want to use for my other library that I'm creating.

It is working correctly but I'm having trouble getting rid of the buffer structure that I'm creating in one of the functions. The following snippets should help illustrate my problem:

C header:

```
//dbuffer.h
...

typedef struct{
    char *pStorage;
    int *pPosition;
    int next_position;
    int number_of_strings;
    int total_size;
    }DBUFF; 
...
```

C source:

```
//dbuffer.c
...
DBUFF* dbuffer_init(char *init_pArray)
    {
    //Find out how many elements the array contains
    int size = sizeof_pArray(init_pArray);                         

    //Initialize buffer structure
    DBUFF *buffer = malloc(sizeof(DBUFF));                                       

    //Initialize the storage
    buffer->pStorage = malloc( (sizeof(char)) * (size) );

    strncpy( &(buffer->pStorage)[0] ,  &init_pArray[0] , size);
    buffer->number_of_strings = 1;

    buffer->total_size = size;
    buffer->next_position = size; //size is the next position because array allocates elements from 0 to (size-1)

    //Initialize the position tracker which keeps record of starting position for each string
    buffer->pPosition = malloc(sizeof(int) * buffer->number_of_strings );
    *(buffer->pPosition + (buffer->number_of_strings -1) ) = 0;

    return buffer;
    }

void dbuffer_destroy(DBUFF *buffer)
    {
    free(buffer->pStorage);
    free(buffer);
    }
...
```

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dbuffer.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    DBUFF *buff; 

    buff = dbuffer_init("Bring the action");
    dbuffer_add(buff, "Bring the apostles");
    printf("BUFFER CONTENTS: ");
    dbuffer_print(buff); 

    dbuffer_destroy(buff);

    // Looks like it has been succesfully freed because output is garbage
    printf("%s\n", buff->pStorage);   

    //Why am I still able to access struct contents after the pointer has been freed ?
    printf("buff total size: %d\n", buff->total_size);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Output:

```
BUFFER CONTENTS: Bring the action/0Bring the apostles/0
��/�
buff total size: 36

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 94ms)
```

**Question:**

Why am I still able to access struct contents using the line below after the pointer to the struct has been freed ?

```
printf("buff total size: %d\n", buff->total_size);
```

Comment: `free` doesn't make pre allocated memory not accessible. Simply it free that space to be used for next `malloc`. Then you can still access it, but is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: That's udefined behaviour . You should not access memory after it is freed .

Comment: The code misses to `free()` what had been allocated to `buffer->pPosition`.

Comment: @alk Thank you, another user just pointed that out to me, well spotted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've called `free()` on the allocated pointer, attempt to make use of the pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should not be doing that.

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §7.22.3.4, *`free()` function*

> The `free()` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. [..]

It never say's anything about a *cleanup*, which you might be (wrongly) expecting.

Just to add clarity, calling `free()` does not always actually *free up* the allocated physical memory. It just enables that pointer (memory space) to be allocated again (returning the same pointer, for example) for successive calls to `malloc()` and family. After calling `free()`, that pointer is not supposed to be used from your program anymore but `C` standard does not guarantee of a *cleanup* of the allocated memory.

Comment: I am aware that 'free'  is not supposed to clean up the memory. I'm expecting however that the free will break the pointer link to the contents of the memory as I have proven with 'printf("%s\n", buff->pStorage);' after 'free' was called. but not with the whole buff structure. I expected to be left with dangling pointer but it clearly isn't the case!

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer You see, _cleanup_ or _breaking_ or _setting to NULL_, neither of these is (are) mandated by C standard. :)

Comment: So by Freeing the memory I might be left with dangling pointer to garbage or a SEEMINGLY working pointer ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer you __will__ be left with dangling pointer to garbage. and that `SEEMINGLY working` thing is the beauty of the UB. :)

Comment: That's highly disappointing, is there a way I can prove to myself that the SEEMINGLY working pointer was ACTUALLY free'd and the reason it's working is UB instead of possible errors in the code? ALSO: I have done everything correctly to free that pointer, right ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer Well, there is a much-used programming style,  setting the freed pointer to NULL immediately after the call to `free()` can cause a segmentation fault on any successive attempt to use the pointer. That way, you can be alerted of any mistake.

Answer (score 6):

If any attempt is made to read memory that has been `free`d can crash your program. Or they might not. As far as the language is concerned, its ***undefined behaviour***.

Your compiler won't warn you about it(*or stop you from accessing it*). But clearly don't do this after calling `free` -

```
printf("buff total size: %d\n", buff->total_size);
```

As a good practice you can set the `free`d pointer to `NULL` .

Comment: My approach to programming is **Proof not promises** so I decided to be a bit frisky and see if I get a garbage output when accessing freed pointer which I didn't and it highly confused me.  Is setting the freed pointer to NULL a common/professional practice ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer  Setting it to `NULL` is a common and a good practice. So that if you access it you will generally get a Segmentation Fault (**Better than any unknown problem**) that would tell you error has occurred.

Comment: Okay so inside my dbuffer_destroy function I've done as you advised :
    buffer->pStorage = NULL;
    buffer = NULL; after these have been freed.

and it LITERALLY didn't make any difference for me . why ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer  _No difference_ in what sense ? What did you expect from it ?

Comment: I expected the program to crash or the line printf("buff total size: %d\n", buff->total_size); in main to give me garbage since the address of the buff pointer is now = NULL

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer But maybe didn't set `buff->total_size` to `NULL`  as you access that.

Answer (score 3):

free() call will just *mark* the memory in heap as available for use. So you still have the pointer pointing to this memory location but it's not available anymore for you. Thus, the next call to malloc() is likely to assign this memory to the new reservation.

To void this situations normally once you free() the memory allocated to a pointer you should set it to NULL. De-referencing NULL is UB also but at least when debugging you can see tha pointer should not be used because it's not pointing to a valid memory address.

Answer (score 2):

[too long for a comment]

To allow your "destructor" to set the pointer passed to `NULL` modify your code like this:

```
void dbuffer_destroy(DBUFF ** buffer)
{
  if ((NULL == buffer) || (NULL == *buffer))
  {
     return;
  }

  free((*buffer)->pPosition);
  free((*buffer)->pStorage);
  free(*buffer);
  *buffer = NULL;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
  ...
  dbuffer_destroy(&buff);
  ...
```

Comment: Why did you change the function parameter to double pointer? it seems that you're doing essentially the same thing that I was doing(which didn't work for me) but with additional level of redundant steps ?

Comment: What you call "*redundant*" is essentially necessary to have the changes to  `NULL`  being reflected inside the pointer-variable hold by the caller. Please note the different way of calling the function. @ShadyProgrammer

Comment: Yes I've noted that you're passing the **address of the pointer** not the **address of the contents the pointer is pointing to** and inside the fucntion what you're doing is you're setting the contents of pointer to pointer ( which is address of the contents the pointer is pointing to) to null which is what I was doing all along

Comment: "*which is what I was doing all along*" are you? Where? And please be aware that if you do so in the code you show, that is inside `dbuffer_destroy()` the `NULL` will not be reflected on the level of the calling function, that is `buff` won't be equal `NULL` after `dbuffer_destroy()`  returned. C is pass by value. @ShadyProgrammer

Comment: I've modified my function to what you suggested in your answer, tested it, and I was finally able to destroy that structure! I bow down to you. The key thing was that  **"buff won't be equal NULL after dbuffer_destroy() returned. C is pass by value."** which I didn't know about. Can you explain why that was the case because I mean I was passing a POINTER afterall.

Comment: when you pass a pointer the variable of the parameter has the address of the original pointer variable. So, if you change the value of the parameter ( setting to NULL )  you are not changing the value of the original variable the only thing you are doing is changing the address the parameter is pointing to.